# Using HTML to present stuctured data

Tags: html, user-interface, presentation

I have a question about how to present some structured data using HTML.

I have some tree-like data, which you might normally present using sections and subsections (i.e. `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.) and/or using nested lists (i.e. lists whose items contain lists of sub-items).

An example of this data is a to-do list, which has tasks that include sub-tasks and sub-sub-tasks.

Each of these data also has associated properties, for example:

- `bool completed;`
- `DateTime completionDate;`
- `Priority priority;`

My question is, what do you suggest as a good way to present this data on one page, using HTML?

---

My first idea is to present it as a table:

- One of the table's columns shows the task or sub-task
- Other columns in each row show the values of the properties (e.g. "completed", etc.) associated with that task

My problem with this is that showing all tasks and sub-tasks in one table column would lose the information about how the tasks are nested: for example it wouldn't show that the second row is actually a subtask of the first row. Can you suggest a way to work-around that problem? I thought of decorating items with a variable number of chevrons like '>' to show how deeply nested each item is, for example:

```
TASK                    COMPLETED

Some major task            No
> A subtask                Yes
> Another subtask          Yes
> > A sub-subtask          Yes
Next major task            No
```

Some problems with that however are:

- It might look ugly, and I'm not sure that it's as intuitively understandable and as readable as it can be. Might some other ornament, or simply variable-length whitespace indent, be better?
- I don't see an elegant way to encode it using HTML+CSS; for example, would you insert the ornament using HTML, or insert it using CSS; and if using CSS, would that be by adding something like `class="level1"` through `class="level6"` to show the nesting level?

---

A second way would be to present it as text that flows vertically, for example ...

```
<h1>Some major task</h1>
<p>Completed: no.</p>
<h2>A subtask</h2>
...etc...
```

... which I will do as well, but I also want a view which lets the reader scan the column of property values, which is easier when the property values are aligned in a column instead of interspersed with other text.

---

This is more about UI design than coding, but ... I'm surely not the first person to want to display this kind of data, but I don't remember having seen any examples, so I'd like to ask you.

Comment: The question title isn't very descriptive/specific: please feel free to improve it if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI component you want is called a TreeTable (or Tree Table). There are [various implementations](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+tree+table) of it in Javascript/HTML. Here's [one](http://source.mihelac.org/2005/7/28/html-treetable) that uses Javascript. Here's [another one](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/tree-table/) that's pure HTML/CSS (but doesn't collapse/expand)

Comment: Wow, I guess there is a right answer after all. +1 for understanding the question that in retrospect makes perfect sense. :-)

Comment: It's also called a "Column tree", e.g. http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=column+tree and http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about nesting in the hierarchal structure of HTML. By its very nature you don't really have to do any special work at all.

A simple, recursive list is all you need, without any special considerations for depth or anything. You can even add expand-collapse functionality to any level if you want without much extra work.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="task-group">
      <span class="task-title">Task 1</span>
      <span class="task-status">Complete</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="task-group">
            <span class="task-title">Task 1a</span>
            <span class="task-status">Complete</span>
          </div>
        <li>
          <div class="task-group">
            <span class="task-title">Task 1b</span>
            <span class="task-status">Incomplete</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you just style each task-group to have a relative margin to its parent so that the nesting becomes recursive. Set up fancy (or no) bullets for the tasks with `li`'s style, and customize the positioning of the `task-status` class to make it lay out the way you want it.

You can also get lower subtasks to recursively inherit smaller text size by setting a relative text-size in the CSS. Something like `.75em`, so that each level is three quarters smaller than the previous level.

Something like this:

```
.task-group {
   font-size: .75em;
   margin-left: 1em;
}
.task-title {
   text-decoration: underline;
   float: left;
}
.task-status {
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a neat answer; but how would you change the 'float: left' and 'float: right' to accomodate there being more than two columns (e.g. 4 columns, consisting of one title plus three different properties)? And, should floated items have an explicit width?

Comment: @ChrisW, well, in the case that you have more than a few columns you obviously can't use floating reliably. Also, I leave picking widths and whatnot to you. My point was simply that HTML's hierarchal nature makes this kind of nesting very straightforward. However I believe that ykaganovich's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's a pity if your suggestion doesn't work for more than two columns, because it's attractive: because, it looks like it would enable using the same HTML both for the (first) table-like layout and for the (second) text-like layout, with only a change in CSS. Assuming that I can and do specify a width for each item, why do you say that I "obviously can't use floating reliably"? An example of floating more than two items seems to be http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction09.htm

Comment: @ChrisW: Floating more than one item is fine, but when the widths of things are dynamic it doesn't end up looking like a table anymore. Table-less CSS is very hard to align both horizontally and vertically at the same time, unless the widths and heights of everything is fixed, in which case things align only by coincidence. I am generally very much in favour of dynamic layouts over fixed layouts, as I find fixed layouts to be cumbersome and inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

UL, OL and LI are good for this purpose. Structuring it as [JSON](http://json.org) is even better. You can render the HTML from JSON in any way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The question has no right or wrong answer. But I'll answer this question within a question.

> If using CSS, would that be by adding
>   something like class="level1" through
>   class="level6" to show the nesting
>   level?

No. You would use the appropriate selector in CSS.

```
li {
  // level one style
}

li li 
{
  // level two style
} 

etc.
```

Comment: I was thinking of having a class attribute which I could add to the <td> that contains the section title. I hadn't seen how to use nested lists combined with table-column-like properties.

Comment: Here's an example of a tabular list: http://www.tbrown.org/ideas/tabularlist/

Although I think I would only use lists for the branches, and use tables for the leaves.